# Zend Order by Cast with mysql

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I am using Zend Framework with a MySQL database.

Can zend select produce something like this ?

```
SELECT * FROM `abc` ORDER BY CAST( `something` AS SIGNED ), `other` ASC
```

at the moment i give raw sql query since don't know how to make zend use `$select->order(..)` and obtain that query...

I'm thinking maybe not all db support this so zend doesn't has it or why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can use Zend_Db_Expr class instance and pass it to order method

Comment: raw sql: SELECT * FROM `abc` ORDER BY CAST( `something` AS SIGNED ), `other` ASC

zend query:

$this->select()
  ->order(new Zend_Db_Expr("CAST( `something` AS SIGNED )").", other");

Comment: i used this $select>order(new Zend_Db_Expr("CAST( `alfa` AS SIGNED )"))
    ->order('beta ASC');

Answer (score 0):

There is no such keyword in zend. We cannot make casting at the time of fetching the data but we can make casting after the fetching the data.

Comment: but zend must not cast anything, he must tell the database to cast

Comment: yah, I know but in zend the query are execute like
$table->select()->where();

you can cast query by making change in DB_Table_Row_Abstract file.
make your custom query in that file

Answer (score 0):

***A ZF2 2019 answer:***

```
$select->order(new Expression("CAST($orderColumn AS CHAR) $orderDirection"));
```

Since `new Zend_Db_Expr` do not work anymore ("renamed")